# Adding New Items With jQuery And No Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am wanting to enable the user to add items to a view model with jQuery and no ajax.

The reason I do not want to use ajax is because without ajax user must click save, and this creates less chance of them accidentally changing something.

I have it working, but it seems like a bit of a hack.

```
'<tr>'+
'<td class="detail-priority">' +
'<input id="ComplianceSeverityLevel_4__ComplianceSeverityLevelId" type="hidden" value="-1" name="ComplianceSeverityLevel[4].ComplianceSeverityLevelId" data-val-required="The ComplianceSeverityLevelId field is required." data-val-number="The field ComplianceSeverityLevelId must be a number." data-val="true">' +
'<input id="ComplianceSeverityLevel_4__Priority" class="valid" type="text" value="0" name="ComplianceSeverityLevel[4].Priority" data-val-required="The Priority field is required." data-val-number="The field Priority must be a number." data-val="true">' +
'</td>' +
'</tr>'
```

I basically just copy the HTML that ASP.NET MVC generates, set the ID value to -1 so that it knows to create a new entry.

I also have to generate the array index. This doesn't seem like an optimal way to go about this. There are a few articles on the subject but they all involve ajax.

Is there anyway that I can do this more efficently?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: I'm assuming you mean ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Yes ASP.NET MVC. I am sorry I am fairly new at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a "new" item to the model in your controller (or in your view if you prefer that). This way you have at least 1 item in your collection.

Now, instead of adding hardcoded HTML (which you have to update whenever you change the View), you can [.clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the last item on the page and update the necessary IDs.

When submitting, you can either disable the input fields of the last item in your HTML so the empty item isn't included, or you can check server-side to exclude the last item.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I cannot think of a robust enough regular expression to update all the ID's with. If I replace say '1' with '2' I might do damage to other data.

Comment: You can check for `_1` or `_1__`. If you're still worried, you can hardcode `ComplianceSeverityLevel_`. Yes, it's hardcoding, but it's a lot better than hardcoding all HTML.

Comment: I'm thinking I might have to do that, I cannot see any alternative. Thanks for your help on this. I will leave this topic open over night to see if there are any other suggestions.